# How to Pass Json data between two screens using useHistory hook in web

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Ford', color: 'Red' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Hyundai', color: 'Blue' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Hyundai', color: 'Blue' },
];
const routeChange = () => {
    navigate.push(`/newclaimreview`);
  };
```

Here I am navigating to newclaimreview screen upon clicking a button.
How to pass data as a parameter and how to receive data in newclaimreview screen

Comment: const routeChange = () => {
    navigate("/newclaimreview", {
      data
});
  };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data using state parameters from one screen to another screen like that.

```
navigate.push({
  pathname: '/newclaimreview',
  state: data_you_need_to_pass
});
```

You get params which you have sent in next screen

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location.state);
```